# How to manipulate other website data?

Tags: html, apache, api, tomcat, glassfish

So for this college project, I was creating an app which uses API to retrieve data, store and output in a certain way.

But I have realised the API is very primitive and doesn't provide the appropriate data required.

Hence I now need your help with something that I don't even know what it is called.

I need a technology to read the webpage and returns the REQUESTED webpages' HTML, so I can create a algorithm to extract the appropriate data myself.

I am aware that if it was my own website, I could use javascript to do something like:

> **var unfilteredData = document.getElementbyId("x");**
>
> *> or*
>
> **var unfilteredData = document.getElementbyId("x"),innerHtml;**

But I need to know how I can access this (the elements/ tags), for website that is not in my domain.

FYI, I am aware of JSON, AJAX, XHttpRequest or whatever you wish to call it:

```
function loadKnownXML() {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } 
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "xmlhttp_info.txt", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

HOWEVER, These xhttprequest ONLY works for API, etc.

I need something where I enter "http://www.bbc.com/" and it will give me the (entire) HTML PAGE of the BBC website.

Answer (score 1):

It is called crawling, and what technique you could use depends on the kind of websites you want to crawl. If you want to crawl static webpages without any javascript, or javascript wich is just for usability and not content, than you could use cli tools like curl or wget, or ann HTTP libraries in whatever language you are using. A good example for a ready to use web crawler from the ruby world would be [mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize).

If you want to crawl pages which rely heavily on javascript for rendering content, than you need something more sophisticated like a scriptable browser. Examples are [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) (based on webkit, headless), [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org) (based on Firefox's Gecko). Or you could use something like [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) to remotely script almost any browser.